# Reading and deleting a record in a single action

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have an API connected to a database, which feeds clients with data using GET method. Client calls GET and gets a single data row. I need that row to be deleted from the database as soon as its read, so that another client cannot get the same data again (in case 2 clients call GET at the same time).

The code on the API GET right now is:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Data>>GetData(){

var data = await context.Data.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

context.Remove(data);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();

return data;

}
```

Does this do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

No this will not protect from two readers reading the same record. The window where multiple readers can see the row is most likely so large that you should be able to reproduce it by hand with two tabs in your browser.

For ensuring one reader you will need to some SQL.

Here's one way:
Stage 1. Extend the table with `Reader` column

Stage 2. Read and delete

1. Update the top 1 row

   ```
   WITH one AS
    (
    SELECT  TOP 1 *
    FROM    your_table 
    WHERE   ReaderId is null
    ORDER BY some_column ASC/DESC
    )
   UPDATE  one
   SET     Reader = @ReaderId
   ```

   where ReaderId may be a `Guid.NewGuid()`
2. Read the row that belongs to you:
   `.Where(r => r.ReaderId = ReaderId)`
3. Delete the row

Comment: I dont have any ID on the clients...